# Applying Generalized Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I came across this question today:

> Let $Q$ be the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions in $L^1(Q)$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_Q f_n = \int_Qf$ and $f_n$ converges pointwise everywhere to $f$. Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \int_Ef$ for any measurable subset $E \subset Q$.

I think the idea of the Generalized Dominated convergence theorem is hidden in this question, I will include the statement:

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converge pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $f$.  Suppose there is a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of integrable functions on $E$ that converge pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_E$ $g_n$ = $\int_E$ $g$, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_E$ $f_n$ = $\int_E$ $f$.

Since we are given $$\int_Q f_n \rightarrow \int_Qf,$$ we set $g_n = f_n+f$ and so by the triangle inequality we have $g_n \geq |f_n - f|$. The hypothesis that $f_n$ converges to $f$ everywhere on $Q$ implies that $g_n$ converges to $g = 2f$ and clearly $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_Qg_n = \int_Qg.$$ Hence we can invoke the generalized DCT to obtain $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_Q|f_n - f| = \int_Q \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|f_n-f|=0.$$ This will imply that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E|f_n-f| =0$$ for any measurable subset $E \subset Q$. Now we just need to prove that this will imply $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \int_E f.$$ We use the fact that the map $f \mapsto \int_E|f|$ is a norm which we will denote by $|f|_1$. By the triangle inequality, we have $$||f_n-f||_1 \geq ||f_n|_1-|f|_1| \geq 0$$ and since the left hand side tends to $0$, we have $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_E f_n - \int_Ef\right) = 0$$ as required. Does this work?